# Using || and && in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

So when I was trying to set up my loop conditions to be `for(char input = ' '; input != 'X' || input != 'E';)` it wouldn't exit out the loop with either 'X' or 'E'. I was just wondering why something like `for(char input = ' '; input != 'X' && input != 'E';)` does work ?

Comment: Language? Would help, if for no other reason than syntax highlighting...

Comment: It's java, I forgot to add it in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `true || false` is `true` (but `true && false` is `false`).

So,

- when you try to exit by passing `X`, the condition is effectively `true` because it is not `E`;
- when you try to exit by passing `E`, the condition is effectively `true` because it is not `X`.

Hence, the loop continues and doesn't exit.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks for the clarification !